# How create Nested JSON with mysqli group_concat?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, mysqli

Extracting Values from Nested JSON Data !

```
$response = array();
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "
    SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(':', Name) SEPARATOR ',') AS Result 
    FROM mytbl GROUP BY id
");
mysqli_num_rows($result);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $char = array("id"=>$row["id"], "char"=>[$row["Result"]]);
        array_push($response,array('Attr'=>$char));
    }
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

i added photo for what i need

[image: Nested Json Data]

Comment: Please replace the image with code. Using a 100KB image for 100 bytes of code speeds up global warming, and .. you know.. it also kills kittens.

Comment: My English not good .. that's only way to explain what i need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Explode it with PHP

```
$response = array();
$result =mysqli_query($conn, "

SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(':', Name) SEPARATOR ',') AS Result 
FROM mytbl GROUP BY id ");
mysqli_num_rows($result);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $char = array("id"=>$row["id"],"char"=>explode(',', $row["Result"]));
    array_push($response,array('Attr'=>$char));
  }
}
```